# What is best... ASP.NET Core Module processPath to .exe or to .dll

Tags: asp.net-core, web-config

When you publish an Asp.net core application it produces a web.config with the following configuration

`<aspNetCore processPath=".\MyApplication.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />`

You can use **processPath=".\MyApplication.exe"** or **processPath=".\MyApplication.dll"**

Does anyone knows the pros & cons of each on and when should we use which?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, I don’t think you have much of a choice there. There are two options as far as I am aware:

- Running a self-contained application by specifying the path to the `.exe`.
- Running a framework-dependent application by specifying the path to the `dotnet` executable and passing the path to the application DLL.

That’s also what [the documentation suggests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configuration-of-aspnet-core-module-with-webconfig) and what happens automatically when you publish your ASP.NET Core application from Visual Studio or through the dotnet CLI. So the transformed `web.config` should have either of the following configurations:

```
<!-- self-contained application -->
<aspNetCore processPath=".\MyApp.exe" … />

<!-- framework-dependent application -->
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApp.dll" … />
```

The framework-dependent application configuration here assumes that the `dotnet` executable is in the PATH environment variable. Otherwise, you can also specify an absolute path to it.

I personally have never seen `<aspNetCore processPath=".\MyApp.dll" … />` and would be surprised if that worked because the ASP.NET Core hosting module for IIS does not actually come with any knowledge how to launch .NET Core applications (at least as far as I know). That’s why you usually have to specify the path to an exectuable (either the application’s `.exe` itself, or the runtime executable).

As for which of these options to use, it really depends on how you want to run your application. If you publish your application as self-contained, then the runtime is already included and you do that in order to be independent of the global runtime that may be installed on the machine. If you publish your application as framework-dependent, you rely on a framework being available on the machine (which can also be updated centrally etc.).

Comment: Hello and thank you for your time! :) You are right about processPath and arguments... I expressed it wrong... However, I wanted to ask exactly what you answered above... What happens behind the scenes when you run it as self-contained or as framework-dependent, and which of them is better when we host a net.core app inside the iis

Comment: I would like to add that this only applies to "portable" versions. If published exclusively for an explicit target runtime (e.g. x64), the generation of an executable file (e.g. for x64 an .exe file) with corresponding setting in the processPath of the web.config is done here as well.

Comment: @Grimm _“If published exclusively for an explicit target runtime”_ – That’s what a self-contained application refers to.

Comment: No, that's two different things. You can deploy framework-dependent but for x64 exclusively. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/ ("...framework-dependent executable for a specific platform..."). When you're using that one, you will get an exe file in the processPath in your web.config though it is not a self-contained application.

Comment: @Grimm Ah, cool, I learned something new – Thanks, that’s really good to know! :)

Comment: You‘re welcome! In fact, you can save a lot of upload data during deployment by selecting the target platform (which should be known in most cases).